# ActiveRecord::QueryCache#call slow on Heroku with pg:backups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, activerecord

Lately we've had trouble on our Rais 4.2.7.1 app every night, we start seeing a bunch of really slow `ActiveRecord::QueryCache#call` calls even though our traffic is relatively low in the middle of the night:

[image: NewRelic Dashboard]

We're running on Heroku using Puma and the app is very job heavy, for which we use Sidekiq. During the day it works fine but every night we get these spikes of extremely slow response times via the API that seem to originate with `ActiveRecord::QueryCache#call`.

The only thing I can find from our app that might be causing this is we have heroku pg:backups enabled, and the night of the above image the backup began running at 3:06 which is the exact time you see that first `ActiveRecord::QueryCache#call` spike in the newrelic graph. The backup finished an hour later, however (around the biggest spike), but as you can see the spikes continued until around 5am.

Could this be caused by pg:backups? (Our database is about 19GB), or could it be something else entirely? Is there a good way to avoid this cache call or speed it up? I don't fully understand WHY it would be so slow or exist at all in the transaction list. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funnily enough, we've been investigating this lately after seeing similar behaviour. There is a definite performance hit caused by `pg:backups` on large databases. Notice the big spike just after 1am, when backup kicks in:

[image: Load average]

*DB size is >100GB*

It's not that surprising, and in fact Heroku do have [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-data-safety-and-continuous-protection#the-performance-impact-of-logical-backups) on this, which suggests that you should only use `pg:backups` for databases under 20GB.

For larger databases, creating a follower and taking the backup from that is preferable. Annoyingly for high availability databases, it doesn't appear that you can read from the standby.

---

I can't shed much light on `ActiveRecord::QueryCache` though, so the rest of this post is speculation, and maybe the starting point for further investigation. Happy to delete/amend if someone more knowledgable can weigh in :-)

Heroku's docs do say that the backup process *will evict well cached data from non-Postgres caches*, so this could represent your workers repopulating that cache many times over.

It may also be worth having a look at [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/26666). Could your workers be reusing connections and receiving dirty query caches?

Comment: I just came across that same documentation regarding `pg:backups` and database size. Interestingly enough, our database used to be about 40GB and this didn't seem to be an issue then. But I'm going to try disabling it for a night (relying on continuous protection) and seeing if that makes a difference.